# How to correctly collect json data in specific order

Tags: javascript, json

I'm really new to this so sorry if my language would be not "`technical`". I'll learn fast. I have `json` object and im trying to find the correct way to gather the information in separate arrays the correct way

I'm using `map` function to separate each key to a separate key because some keys belongs to another array and im getting a little bit confused. I would love for some explanations.

I added my expected solution in the bottom of my question, if thats help if im not clear.

Following is the json object:

```
var json_museums = {
    "museums_costs": [
        {
            "museumType": "Art",
            "costs": [
                {
                    "date": "2018-10-01",
                    "employees": 1082220.3945979946,
                    "outsource": 9585.8794674401543
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-11-01",
                    "employees": 1056643.6756958894,
                    "outsource": 11018.898987932616
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-12-01",
                    "employees": 1022322.1218654147,
                    "outsource": 11954.748339502334
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "museumType": "History",
            "costs": [
                {
                    "date": "2018-10-01",
                    "employees": 91336.329372028267,
                    "outsource": 0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-11-01",
                    "employees": 78130.417193652393,
                    "outsource": 0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-12-01",
                    "employees": 100755.62136033915,
                    "outsource": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "museumType": "Culture",
            "costs": [
                {
                    "date": "2018-10-01",
                    "employees": 66604.417069221658,
                    "outsource": 0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-11-01",
                    "employees": 63882.129662868538,
                    "outsource": 0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-12-01",
                    "employees": 108781.84734382466,
                    "outsource": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "museumType": "News",
            "costs": [
                {
                    "date": "2018-10-01",
                    "employees": 0,
                    "outsource": 1452.6775522557543
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-11-01",
                    "employees": 0,
                    "outsource": 2366.423254655545
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-12-01",
                    "employees": 0,
                    "outsource": 3485.5840149129986
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "museumType": "Science",
            "costs": [
                {
                    "date": "2018-10-01",
                    "employees": 3237887.746893588,
                    "outsource": 0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-11-01",
                    "employees": 3218724.4935297123,
                    "outsource": 0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-12-01",
                    "employees": 2925562.2916941536,
                    "outsource": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "museumType": "Religious",
            "costs": [
                {
                    "date": "2018-10-01",
                    "employees": 291293.35185208195,
                    "outsource": 0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-11-01",
                    "employees": 171962.47103846565,
                    "outsource": 0
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-12-01",
                    "employees": 95615.439855929668,
                    "outsource": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

var results = [];



results = json_museums.museums_costs.map(function (x) {
    return [x.museumType, x. visits.map(function(c) { c.date), x.costs.reduce(function (a, b, c) {
        return a + b + c;
    }, 0)]
});


(18) [Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3), Array(3)]
0: (3) ["Art", "2018-10-01",  outsource + employee]
1: (3) ["Art", "2018-11-01",  outsource +employee]
2: (3) ["Art", "2018-12-01",  outsource +employee]
3: (3) ["History", "2018-10-01",  outsource + employee]
4: (3) ["History", "2018-11-01",  outsource + employee]
5: (3) ["History", "2018-12-01",  outsource + employee]
6: (3) ["Culture", "2018-10-01",  outsource + employee]
7: (3) ["Culture", "2018-11-01",  outsource + employee]
8: (3) ["Culture", "2018-12-01",  outsource + employee]
9: (3) ["News", "2018-10-01",  outsource + employee]
10: (3) ["News", "2018-11-01",  outsource + employee]
11: (3) ["News", "2018-12-01",  outsource + employee]
12: (3) ["Science", "2018-10-01",  outsource + employee]
13: (3) ["Science", "2018-11-01",  outsource + employee]
14: (3) ["Science", "2018-12-01",  outsource + employee]
15: (3) ["Religious", "2018-10-01",  outsource + employee]
16: (3) ["Religious", "2018-11-01",  outsource + employee]
17: (3) ["Religious", "2018-12-01",  outsource + employee]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `reduce` the top level array starting with an empty array as an accumulator and *then* `map` over the costs and push the elements of the resulting array to the accumulator:

```js
var json_museums = {"museums_costs":[{"museumType":"Art","costs":[{"date":"2018-10-01","employees":1082220.3945979946,"outsource":9585.8794674401543},{"date":"2018-11-01","employees":1056643.6756958894,"outsource":11018.898987932616},{"date":"2018-12-01","employees":1022322.1218654147,"outsource":11954.748339502334}]},{"museumType":"History","costs":[{"date":"2018-10-01","employees":91336.329372028267,"outsource":0},{"date":"2018-11-01","employees":78130.417193652393,"outsource":0},{"date":"2018-12-01","employees":100755.62136033915,"outsource":0}]},{"museumType":"Culture","costs":[{"date":"2018-10-01","employees":66604.417069221658,"outsource":0},{"date":"2018-11-01","employees":63882.129662868538,"outsource":0},{"date":"2018-12-01","employees":108781.84734382466,"outsource":0}]},{"museumType":"News","costs":[{"date":"2018-10-01","employees":0,"outsource":1452.6775522557543},{"date":"2018-11-01","employees":0,"outsource":2366.423254655545},{"date":"2018-12-01","employees":0,"outsource":3485.5840149129986}]},{"museumType":"Science","costs":[{"date":"2018-10-01","employees":3237887.746893588,"outsource":0},{"date":"2018-11-01","employees":3218724.4935297123,"outsource":0},{"date":"2018-12-01","employees":2925562.2916941536,"outsource":0}]},{"museumType":"Religious","costs":[{"date":"2018-10-01","employees":291293.35185208195,"outsource":0},{"date":"2018-11-01","employees":171962.47103846565,"outsource":0},{"date":"2018-12-01","employees":95615.439855929668,"outsource":0}]}]}

var results = json_museums.museums_costs.reduce((a, x) => {
  a.push(...x.costs.map(cost => [x.museumType, cost.date, cost.outsource + cost.employees]));
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(results);
```

Another way to do this would be with [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), although that is not universally supported.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to transform the object into the desired structure by:

- mapping over `museums_costs`
- inside the above map, map over `cost`. At this point you have sufficient information to construct a unit of required result
- after the above execution a nested array is created. You can flatten it by using [Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
const json_museums = {"museums_costs":[{"museumType":"Art","costs":[{"date":"2018-10-01","employees":1082220.3945979946,"outsource":9585.879467440154},{"date":"2018-11-01","employees":1056643.6756958894,"outsource":11018.898987932616},{"date":"2018-12-01","employees":1022322.1218654147,"outsource":11954.748339502334}]},{"museumType":"History","costs":[{"date":"2018-10-01","employees":91336.32937202827,"outsource":0},{"date":"2018-11-01","employees":78130.41719365239,"outsource":0},{"date":"2018-12-01","employees":100755.62136033915,"outsource":0}]},{"museumType":"Culture","costs":[{"date":"2018-10-01","employees":66604.41706922166,"outsource":0},{"date":"2018-11-01","employees":63882.12966286854,"outsource":0},{"date":"2018-12-01","employees":108781.84734382466,"outsource":0}]},{"museumType":"News","costs":[{"date":"2018-10-01","employees":0,"outsource":1452.6775522557543},{"date":"2018-11-01","employees":0,"outsource":2366.423254655545},{"date":"2018-12-01","employees":0,"outsource":3485.5840149129986}]},{"museumType":"Science","costs":[{"date":"2018-10-01","employees":3237887.746893588,"outsource":0},{"date":"2018-11-01","employees":3218724.4935297123,"outsource":0},{"date":"2018-12-01","employees":2925562.2916941536,"outsource":0}]},{"museumType":"Religious","costs":[{"date":"2018-10-01","employees":291293.35185208195,"outsource":0},{"date":"2018-11-01","employees":171962.47103846565,"outsource":0},{"date":"2018-12-01","employees":95615.43985592967,"outsource":0}]}]};

const result = json_museums.museums_costs.map(museum =>
  museum.costs.map(cost => [
    museum.museumType,
    cost.date,
    cost.employees + cost.outsource
  ])
).flat(1);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Array#reduce and Array#forEach

```js
const data={museums_costs:[{museumType:"Art",costs:[{date:"2018-10-01",employees:1082220.3945979946,outsource:9585.879467440154},{date:"2018-11-01",employees:1056643.6756958894,outsource:11018.898987932616},{date:"2018-12-01",employees:1022322.1218654147,outsource:11954.748339502334}]},{museumType:"History",costs:[{date:"2018-10-01",employees:91336.32937202827,outsource:0},{date:"2018-11-01",employees:78130.41719365239,outsource:0},{date:"2018-12-01",employees:100755.62136033915,outsource:0}]},{museumType:"Culture",costs:[{date:"2018-10-01",employees:66604.41706922166,outsource:0},{date:"2018-11-01",employees:63882.12966286854,outsource:0},{date:"2018-12-01",employees:108781.84734382466,outsource:0}]},{museumType:"News",costs:[{date:"2018-10-01",employees:0,outsource:1452.6775522557543},{date:"2018-11-01",employees:0,outsource:2366.423254655545},{date:"2018-12-01",employees:0,outsource:3485.5840149129986}]},{museumType:"Science",costs:[{date:"2018-10-01",employees:3237887.746893588,outsource:0},{date:"2018-11-01",employees:3218724.4935297123,outsource:0},{date:"2018-12-01",employees:2925562.2916941536,outsource:0}]},{museumType:"Religious",costs:[{date:"2018-10-01",employees:291293.35185208195,outsource:0},{date:"2018-11-01",employees:171962.47103846565,outsource:0},{date:"2018-12-01",employees:95615.43985592967,outsource:0}]}]};

const res = data.museums_costs.reduce((a,{museumType,costs})=>{
  costs.forEach(({employees, outsource, date})=>{
    a.push([museumType, date, employees+outsource])
  });
  return a;
},[]);

console.log(res);
```